# Helvetica does not support subsrcipt numbers

Tags: php, utf-8, fonts, tcpdf, subscript

i'm currently working with TCPDF. So far, so good, but I have to use subscript numbers like

```
₂ in CO₂.
```

Unfortunately, helvetica (provided in TCPDF) doesn't support them, it'll end up in

```
? in CO?.
```

Is there any way to fix this or do you know another free font which (~100%) looks lik helvetica that supports subscript numbers? I also need it as .ttf-file (including italic font).

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is tricky (so it doesn't deserve to be closed). PDF (viewers) requires just few predefined fonts, and that are non Unicode (and the non predefined should be Unicode aware), so in general you should embed a font). But a subscript is not a new character, so treat it as `2` with formatting, and so PDF will not have problem (PDF is much more powerful on specifying exactly the formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is probably to use the writeHtml method of tcpdf. Then you can use something along the lines of `CO<sub>2</sub>`. Example can be seen [here](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/).

Comment: In fact, it is discouraged to use Unicode subscripts (they were included just for compatibility of old encodings). OTOH sometime HTML doesn't allow you to use `<sub>`, e.g. on SELECT/OPTION.